# MySQL database design for soccer odds

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

As you know, soccer odds results/history had no end. I want to generate output like this. What is the best practise to design mysql database?

[image]

This is what i got so far:

Table:

```
league: id, league

teams: id, team

odds: id, league_id, date, hometeam_id, awayteam_id, ht, ft,
crown_open_1, crown_open_x, crown_open_2, 
crown_closed_1, crown_closed_x, crown_closed_2, bet365_open_1,....
```

I'm stuck at odds table. How to design for odds table with 1x2 data, open and closed? Or split the data with "|" in 2 column instead of 6?

```
column: crown_open: 1.82|3.35|4.90
column: crown_closed: 2.07|3.05|4.10
```

I guess all this approach can achieve my goal, but what is the best practise for long term? Or any other options?

Based on @Rickjames answer, is this correct? Each bookmarker/type has 3 rows, if 4 bookmarkers then 12 rows for each game. Am i right?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should have a new row for each 'open',

Comment: Now to craft the `SELECTs`.  This will help you decide if the schema is 'good'.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not* combine multiple values into a single column; they will be hard to split apart.  Instead have multiple columns or (usually better) have multiple rows, perhaps in a separate table.

I suspect this might be best:  A table with these columns:

league_id, time, home_id, away_id, ht, ft, type, seq, `open`, closed

Notes:

- type might be `ENUM('crown', 'bet365', ...)
- `seq` is 1,2,3 -- for those 3 columns.  (What is the significance of them?)
- I don't know what to advise on the "3-0", "1-0" column
- Formatting is the job of the application, *not* SQL.
- For the above snippet, there would be 24 rows in the table.